# how a segment in a segment tree be deleted in O(log n) time?

Tags: segment-tree

I just finished reading about segment trees, the proof for insertion with time complexity O(log n) is quite convincing, but I was not able to figure out how deletion can be carried out with same complexity. Also I tried searching for the paper in which segment trees were proposed but was not able to find it , if some one has it can you post the link.
"J.L. Bentley, Algorithms for Klee's rectangle problems. Technical Report"